# Склонение фамилии Такмазян

Tags: ономастика, склонение-фамилий

Простите, я не поняла, что мне делать с фамилией Такмазян... Она не склоняется?

Answer (score 2):

Если женщина Такмазян, то не склоняется. Н-р: Я взял книгу (у кого?) у Сусанны Такмазян,вернул книгу (кому?) Сусанне Такмазян. А м. р. склоняется как существительное 2-го склонения. Н-р: кто? Такмазян
                кого? Такмазян**а**   
                кому? Такмазян**у** и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Мужская склоняется по общему правилу, женская - нет.

А что значит "я не поняла"? Где-то уже обсуждалось?

Answer (score 0):

> кого? Такмазяна 
> кому? Такмазяну и т. д.

Фамилии, оканчивающиеся на согласную, конечно, склоняются. Неужели это распространяется и на фамилии на -ян, так называемые "армянские"?